# How to search database records for a match from user text input and avoid pulling the information? (PHP)

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have two database tables, Recipe Table and Ingredients Table. One recipe can contain many ingredients, and their relationship is linked by the Recipe_ID.

**Recipe Table**

- id
- suitable_for

**RecipeIngredientsMain Table**

- id
- recipe_id
- ingredientname

I have a user input form where users decide the constraints for what Recipes are recommended to them. I have a text box input allowing the user to type in a "specific allergy". This value pulled would then search the ingredients table for a match with the names, and avoid pulling the Recipe_ID if it found a match by querying relationship absence.

For example, if the user inputted "pineapple", if a match was found in the Ingredients table, it would avoid pulling the Recipe_ID.

**The Recipe hasMany relationship in Model:**

```
public function ingredients()
{
return $this->hasMany(Ingredients::class, 'recipe_id');
}
```

**Pulling the user inputs:**

```
$suited = $request->suitable_for;
$specificallerg = $request->specific_allergen;
```

**The code in the Controller:**

```
$recipenew = Recipe::where('recipe.suitable_for', $suited)
    ->whereDoesntHave('ingredients', function($QBspecificallergens) use($specificallerg) {
        $QBspecificallergens->where('recipeingredientsmain.ingredientname', 'like', '%specificallerg%');
      })->pluck('id');
```

The code runs, but my problem is a logic error as it is searching in 'ingredientname' for literally "%specificallerg%" rather than the value that is inputted. How can I fix this?

Comment: `('recipeingredientsmain.ingredientname', 'like', '%'.$specificallerg.'%');` you were passing a string instead of the variable.

Comment: Personally i would make a different table just for the ingredients, since you could want the same ingredient for other recipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a string that you are requesting from the frontend. Not that one you are searching from the table.

```
$suited = $request->suitable_for;
$specificallerg = $request->specific_allergen;


$recipenew = Recipe::where('recipe.suitable_for', $suited)
    ->whereDoesntHave('ingredients', function($QBspecificallergens) use($specificallerg) {
        $QBspecificallergens->where('recipeingredientsmain.ingredientname', 'like', '%'.$specificallerg.'%');
      })->pluck('id');
```